# SQL Query to convert HHMM to minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a dataset that includes time columns in integer format as HHMM (i.e., 1730 means 5.30 PM). I would like to calculate the difference in time between rows in terms of minutes.

For example, the difference between 1730 (5.30 PM) and 1315 (1.15 PM) should result in 255 (as there are 4 hours and 15 mins difference)

Is there any way to make some calculations over time values in integer format to convert them to minutes?

So far I have tried the following to convert HHMM integer to minutes:

```
MOD(a,100) + (a DIV 100 ) * 60
```

But it does not work with error 'no viable alternative at input'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You are right, I should have added my work so far. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: If you add it now (using the edit under the question) if it makes the question answerable, we can reopen your question

Comment: Added current progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to convert the number to minutes without changing the integer format. From minutes, you can do any operation between column values like this :

`((a % 100) + (FLOOR(a/100)) *60)`

Where a is an integer in the HHMM time format.

Hope this is helpful to others.
Best regards.